# data is missing/getting truncate while copy from NCLOB datatype column in oracle sql devloper

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper, nclob

I work on C# application which generate the details of employee and also application activity get logged in to logger in database(oracle sql devloper).so i ran the application its response was about of 1000+ lines and same get logged in to database LOG_MESSAGE which has column MESSAGE where application response message get captured(which was 1000+ lines in application). but when i copy and paste the message to clip board it only shows 200 lines. I tried exporting the data but still few lines visible followed by ...

I have checked message data type was NCLOB. please help to find how the full message can we copy to clipboard and how it can be seen.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: application is very big, its live project and also i cant share the message / response as it is confidential.